# Update many multiple data with tables hasmany and belongsTo?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, has-many, belongs-to

sorry for my english

I want two tables

**Invoices**

- id
- user_id
- name
- created_at
- update_at

**Invoicesitems**

- id
- invoice_id
- title
- createad_at
- update_at

**Models**

```
class Invoices extends eloquent{
   public function invoicesitems(){
       return $this->hasMany('Invoicesitem');
   }
}

class Invoicesitems extends eloquent{
   public function invoices(){
       return $this->belongsTo('Invoice');
   }
}
```

Now, for update the items of my invoices?
Example my invoices have 5 item, i need update to 10 items

first delete all items of my invoices and insert new ???

```
$invoices = Invoices::findOrFail($id);
$dataupdate = array(
  'user_id' => Input::get('user'),
  'name' => Input::get('name'),
);
$invoices->fill($dataupdate);
$invoices->save();
```

//Ok update invoices, now how to update items?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your business logic allows - you can just replace the invoice items.

```
$invoice = Invoices::findOrFail($id);
$dataupdate = array(
    'user_id' => Input::get('user'),
    'name' => Input::get('name'),
 );
 $invoice->update($dataupdate);

 // replace invoice items
 $invoice->invoicesitems()->delete();
 $invoice->invoicesitems()->create($invoiceItems);
```

Note! This is quite straight solution. You can improve by using `insert()` method instead of `create()` for batch insert.

Comment: this solution had thought before, but wanted to know if there was another way to solve it, but I keep looking for that solution and apply this.

Comment: There should be proper way to deal with this requirement. however its better solution till get proper way. Thanks